# Secure internet privacy in home at router level

Tags: privacy, router, monitoring

We have a modem/router at home that provides internet services to each of the tenants in the home. These are all students and none of them are network experts. But there has been a dispute that they maybe peeping into websites others are watching. Their websites can be monitored by ISP which is fine with them. The problem is the router also records the websites visited. And these can be accessed by home members. Can some settings be tweaked at the router level so that the students have peace of mind? The issue is not so serious as if one of them knows other's banking passwords he/she will take out money because they are decent students. But privacy is lost. If there are some ways of tweaking the router so that the home members cannot know each others web activity, it will put everyone to rest. VPNs seem to slow down the speed too much.

Comment: *"Can router settings be tweaked?"* Maybe? We know nothing about your router. Not really an infosec question though, is it? More of a question for your router manufacturer's customer support?

Comment: just don't let them into the router admin, or turn off logging on the router.

Comment: The very first thing to do is set the router to use SecureDNS so nobody outside can even see the domain names visited by your tenants.  All you have to do is put in 8.26.56.26 and 8.20.247.20 as the DNS server entries in the router.  The second thing is to have them all install HTTPS-Everywhere in their browsers.  Even non-techies can do that much.  These two steps will make it so even the ISP can't tell what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VPNs are great at hiding what you do from people you know, but most people don't realize that doing so lets total strangers have access to some of your personal details which can be **much worse**.  For that reason, that is not a good solution anyways.

Most (if not all) routers do not log activity by default, but your tenants will necessarily believe that you didn't enable it without having access to its configuration which would be a security hazard for you.

The only good suggestion you can give them is to use secured connection (such as HTTPS).

Using a secured connection does prevent intermediaries from knowing what was exchanged and which page was viewed.  The only thing that may leak is the IP address which very rarely can be traced back to a specific page.

Answer (score 0):

In such situation when mates are worried about their PC security in home network, I'd suggest the following:

1. Update Router firmware to latest
2. Configure strong password to router console (by going to it's IP address)
3. Configure strong WPA2 Wifi password (random one)
4. Turn on network isolation on the router so that one PC cannot access another PC (even via ARP)
5. Get good AV software for each of the PC
6. Disable port sharing on the router (disable UPNP)
7. Make sure every PC is updated with Windows Update and Mac updates
8. Make sure all mobile phones and tablets are updated and do not contain any malware, like some dodgy apps
9. Switch on automatic screen locking (screen saver with locking)
10. Turn on full disk encryption on Desktops, Mobiles and Tablets
11. Issue password change to good random ones, hard to guess passwords (but on a reasonable length). Both user and admin passwords. Disable guest logons.
12. Get rid of suspicious web browser extensions